# How to initiate conversation with a Trusted Application EndPoint using S4B client

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

- I have setup Trusted Application for Skype for Business in the azure
  portal.
- I am able to start a conversation using UCWA API and
  send/receive message.
- I am adding the trusted application end-point
  in Skype For Business client contact and it is getting added as a
  contact in my S4B client as well, but it's presence is shown as
  unknown.
- When I send a message from S4B client to the trusted
  application end point I am getting the error in the chat windows as
  "We couldn't reach demosfb to send this message"

My question is

**Is it possible to start a conversation with a trusted application end-point as we do with a normal contact from Skype For Business client?**

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not supported yet.
There is support for calling into the PSTN number associated with the application trusted end point.